# tokeninput with rails 4, not inserting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So been racking this all day long and my search works fine now, but I can't seem to insert anything new. I tried strong params already and no dice.

Does anyone have experience with token input and had custom primary_keys?

and how does this code work specifically?

```
  def self.tokens(query)
    cooking_types = where("lower(cooking_style) ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
    if cooking_types.empty?
        [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    else
        cooking_types
    end
  end


  def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
    tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id }
    tokens.split(',')
  end


  def cooking_type_tokens=(tokens)
    self.cooking_type_ids = CookingType.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  end
```

Comment: This code looks almost exactly code from the [Railscast episode on Token Input](https://github.com/railscasts/258-token-fields-revised/tree/master/bookstore-tokeninput-after). I assume you haven't forgotten the javascript that goes with this? As to how exactly it works, I would love to see the answer to that too. Especially the <<< >>> surrounding the capture everything block.

Comment: Oh, I actually got this to work, posting my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params.require(:restaurant).permit(some attributes...., :cooking_type_id)
```

Someone posted a solution on the railscast that the parameter should be passed into an array, but it didn't work for me so I just did it as a regular variable (since it's already an array). Also, look at the method for collecting the tokens, I changed it to reflect the parameter being passed. I also want to note that the cooking_type_id is exactly the name of the field as well to the child model.

```
 def cooking_type_id=(tokens)
    self.cooking_type_ids = CookingType.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
 end
```

Let me know if you need more help! It's finally nice to help someone out after all my asking.

```
 def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
    tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id }
    tokens.split(',')
  end
```

This code simple takes all the tokens id and creates a new entry if you're searching for something that's not in your child model.

Comment: Glad you were able to work it out. It is always a good feeling when you figure out something on your own.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing this answer! Those three snippets alone have saved me from the additional hours of frustration I would've spent trying to find a solution to this.